# Which plugin can copy classes from specific dependency into final jar

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-dependency

I created a maven parent project, where I have:

Parent pom:

```
<modules>
    <module>my-project-solution-a</module>
    <module>my-project-solution-b</module>
    <module>my-project-shared-solution</module>
</modules>
```

**my-project-shared-solution** contains the common shared logic for both **my-project-solution-a** and **my-project-solution-b**

**my-project-solution-a:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.solution</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-project-shared-solution</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**my-project-solution-b:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.solution</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-project-shared-solution</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

During the build, I want to copy all classes from **my-project-shared-solution** into **my-project-solution-a** jar and **my-project-solution-b** jar.

BUT I don't want to copy the classes from other dependencies like **spring-webmvc** or **jersey-server**.

So if my other projects want to include **a** or **b** solution, it would still require adding **spring-webmvc** or **jersey-server dependencies**, but it would not be needed to add the shared dependency also, because the classes from the shared one will be packed into **a** and **b** jars.

I tried something with **maven-dependency-plugin** but I don't know how to set this up.

Can you provide some examples of how I could do this during the maven build?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.my.solution</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my-project-shared-solution</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>libs</outputDirectory>
                        <destFileName>somename.jar</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If someone uses your project as dependency, they will automatically get all dependencies of your project as well (transitive dependency resolution). So there is no need to copy classes around.

Comment: True, but I don't want to deploy the shared library, because it is useless for anybody. It is useful only for A and B projects. So if someone checks the maven repo, only A and B dependencies should be visible for them.

Comment: While I don't think this is a good idea, you can probably achieve this with the Maven shade plugin by just shading in one library.

Comment: @victorio, Your question keyword should be `create fat jar`.